# Mac OS X Yosemite public beta not receiving updates

Tags: macos, mac, beta-seed-program

I have a 2010 iMac and I installed Mac OS 10.10 **public beta** last summer, but I haven't received any updates since. My exact version right now is **OS X 10.10 (14A379b)**.

Does anyone know what should i do to get the latest system updates?

Comment: I'd just downed the current OS X Yosemite, now at 10.10.4 (14D2125), from the App Store and install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my guess, your beta may be expired, so the solution would be a final yosemite install from app store.